# Pythonic way of accessing properties in Javascript

Tags: javascript, python

In Python, there is a way to iterate over an array, filter some of the elements and then pop only particular properties of the object. It works in such a way:

```py
elements = [{'name':'1', 'id':1},{'name':'2', 'id':2},{'name':'3', 'id':3}]
filtered_elements = [x['name'] for x in elements if x['id'] == 1]
```

Is there any elegant way to do such a thing in JS?

Comment: JS has Array.map and Array.filter: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Instance_methods

Comment: Don't try to write Pythonic JavaScript. Every language is different and has different idioms. Learn the _JavaScript way_ of doing this, and use it.

Comment: `var f = elements.filter(obj => (obj.id === 1)).map(x => x.name);`

Comment: @JacobIRR note I do t think this will be equivalent, I don't think any JS engine would optimize that to do it in a single pass, I think `Array.filter` is eagerly evaluated. In JS I would just use a regular loop. I'd be curious to know if my assumption is wrong, though

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
var elements = [{'name':'1', 'id':1},{'name':'2', 'id':2},{'name':'3', 'id':3}];
var filtered = elements.filter(x => x.id === 1).map(x => x.name);

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that no JS engine would optimize that to do it in a single pass. IOW `Array.filter` is eagerly evaluated. In JS I would just use a regular loop. I'd be curious to know if my assumption is wrong, though.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga no engine I know of would do a lazy evaluation. Still, there is a possibility, if the callbacks are sure to be pure, then there is little to stop this optimisation path. I suspect that in the future we might see a lazily evaluated array method chains. Still, for now you could use a library like Lodash which will do a lazy evaluated chain with `_(elements).filter(x => x.id === 1).map(x => x.name)` or `_.chain(elements).filter(x => x.id === 1).map(x => x.name)`.